# how to map array of images into two images per list item React JS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mapping

I want to map two images per list item.

I have a slider, that will show two slides per view, so I want it to show 4 images per view.

currently, its just showing the same image which is what I expected it to do, I just don't know how to map two different images per list item.

How would I go about mapping this array so that each list item has two different images?

**SliderComponent.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { IonGrid, IonRow, IonCol } from '@ionic/react';
import { Storage } from "aws-amplify";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";


const SliderComponent = (props) => {

    const { job } = props;
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);


    const settings = {
        infinite: false,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
        speed: 500,
        rows: 1,
        initialSlide: 0,
        autoHeight: false,
        focusOnSelect: true,
        arrows: false,
    };


    useEffect(() => {
        async function onLoad() {

            try {
                const downloadedImage = await getImage(job);
                setImages(downloadedImage);
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }

        onLoad();
    }, []);


    async function getImage(jobID) {
        const imageURL = await Storage.list(`${jobID}/completed/`);
        let imagesToDownload = imageURL
        let imagesAsArray = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < imagesToDownload.length; i++) {
            const imagesDownloaded = await getURLFromS3(imagesToDownload[i]);
            imagesAsArray.push(imagesDownloaded)
        }
        return imagesAsArray
    }

    async function getURLFromS3(fileToDownload) {
        const result = await Storage.get(fileToDownload.key)
        return result;
    }

   return (

        <div>
            <IonGrid>
                <IonRow style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                    <IonCol sizeXs="12" sizeSm="12" sizeMd="10" sizeLg="6" sizeXl="4" >
                        <Slider asNavFor={nav1} ref={slider => (slider2.current = slider)} {...viewSettings}>
                            {images.map((image, i) =>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><img key={i} src={image} /></li> /// First image
                                    <li><img key={i} src={image} /></li> /// Second image
                                </ul>
                            )}
                        </Slider>
                    </IonCol>
                </IonRow>
            </IonGrid>
        </div>
    )
}
export default SliderComponent;
```

**props.job page**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { IonContent, IonHeader, IonPage, IonTitle, IonToolbar, IonGrid, IonCol, IonRow, } from '@ionic/react';
import { API, Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import SliderComponent from '../components/sliderComponent.js'


function propertyInfo(props) {


    return (
        <IonPage>
            <IonHeader>
                <IonToolbar>
                    <IonTitle>prop address</IonTitle>
                </IonToolbar>
            </IonHeader>
            <IonContent>

            <SliderComponent job={props.match.params.id} />

            </IonContent>
        </IonPage>
    );
}
export default withRouter(propertyInfo);
```

Comment: can you include the `props.job` code?

Comment: @Skoltz edited!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could chunk the images array before mapping. If your application has [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chunk), you can use the `_.chunk` function:

> **lodash _.chunk(array, [size=1])**
>
> *Creates an array of elements split into groups the length of size. If array can't be split evenly, the final chunk will be the remaining elements.*

You can also write your own chunk function in a few lines of code:

```
function chunk(array, size) {
  const chunked_arr = [];
  let index = 0;
  while (index < array.length) {
    chunked_arr.push(array.slice(index, size + index));
    index += size;
  }
  return chunked_arr;
}
```

Result (Note: as @HMR pointed out, `image2` is rendered conditionally because if your images array is an odd number, your last chunk will only have one element and would render a broken image tag):

```js
{chunk(images, 2).map(([image1, image2], i) =>
  <ul key={i}>
    <li><img src={image1} /></li>
    {image2 && <li><img src={image2} /></li>}
  </ul>
)}
```

Comment: Will cause an error if images is an odd number. And adding lodash for something you could write in 12 lines of code is maybe not the best idea

Comment: @HMR - You're correct, there would have been a broken image tag if the last chunk only contained 1 element. I modified the example to handle this case. I also added a custom chunk function if lodash is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip, it takes x arrays and will return an array where each element is an element of the arrays passed. So for `[1,2]` and `[3,4]` it will return `[[1,3],[2,4]]`.

When you pass the same array but second array is slice(1) (without the first element) you would pass `[1,2]` and `[2]` resulting in `[[1,2],[2,undefined]]`, then filter out all elements that are in a odd index and you'll get `[[1,2]]`. Here is an example:

```js
const zip = (...arrays) =>
  [
    ...new Array(
      Math.max(...arrays.map((array) => array.length))
    ),
  ].map((_, index) => arrays.map((array) => array[index]));
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
console.log(
  '2 imamages',
  zip(array, array.slice(1)).filter(
    (_, index) => index % 2 === 0
  )
);
console.log(
  '3 imamages',
  zip(array, array.slice(1), array.slice(2)).filter(
    (_, index) => index % 3 === 0
  )
);
```

So now you can do:

```
{zip(images, images.slice(1))
  .filter((_, index) => index % 2 === 0)
  .map(([image1,image2], i) =>
  <ul key={i}>
      <li><img src={image1} /></li> /// First image
      <li>{image2 && <img src={image2} />}</li> /// Second image
  </ul>
)}
```

Please note that if you have an odd number of images then at some point `image2` is undefined that is why the second image is rendered conditionally if there is an image. I also corrected the key prop, you need to set that on the root element.

If you like chunk better then once you have zip chunk is a piece of cake:

```js
const zip = (...arrays) =>
  [
    ...new Array(
      Math.max(...arrays.map((array) => array.length))
    ),
  ].map((_, index) => arrays.map((array) => array[index]));
const chunk = (array, items) =>
  zip(
    ...[...new Array(items)].map((_, index) =>
      array.slice(index)
    )
  ).filter((_, index) => index % items === 0);
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

console.log('2 imamages', chunk(array, 2));
console.log('3 imamages', chunk(array, 3));
```